# Can't call C# method - The name 'sender' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a method that tries to execute an event / method (Download_Click), although for some reason I get:

The name 'sender' does not exist in the current context
The name 'e' does not exist in the current context

The button definitely exists, although for some reason won't work in my code below:

```
private void checkver()
{
    FileInfo sourceFile = new FileInfo("download.zip");
    if (sourceFile.Exists)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.google.com/download.zip");
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.LastModified > sourceFile.LastWriteTime)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File outdated");
            Download_Click(sender, e);
            // use response.GetStream() to download the file.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File in date");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Show the entire method, please, or at least the method signature.

Comment: @Michael: He is; it's `private void checkver()`.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adam Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82187/adam-robinson)'s answer is the right one - but if you really really really want to do that call (no, please don't) (I mean, **REALLY, DON'T**) you can use

```
Download_Click(new object(), new System.EventArgs());
```

Comment: If you're going to invoke it directly, should pass what would be passed in a normal invocation: `Download_Click(Download, EventArgs.Emtpy)`.

Comment: @Adam your actual answer is better - let's not have the idea spreading. Refactoring is the way to go - calling button event handlers feels so... VB 5

Answer (score 5):

You're getting this message because there is no such variable named `sender` (nor is there one named `e`) in your function.

It looks like you've tried to move the code for a button's `Click` event handler out into another function (`sender` and `e` are, by convention, the name of the two parameters sent to an event handler). Unfortunately, the `sender` and `e` variables don't exist in your function because you didn't define them as parameters.

The best thing to do here is to do the same for the `Download` button. Rather than calling its `Click` event handler directly (`Download_Click`), create a new function that performs the download, then just call that function from within `Download_Click`. Then change the code above to call that function directly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to programmatically invoke the buttons click event.  sender and e do not exist in this context.  you could call the click event in this manner.

```
Download_Click(this, new EventArgs());
```

Comment: -1. Invoking a control's event handler and passing garbage parameters is not the preferred way of handling this. If you really need to invoke the event call `Download.PerformClick()`, but I don't believe it's necessary. The code should be refactored out into another function.